# How to permanently resolve "default gateway is not available" after every reboot in Windows 11?

Tags: networking, ethernet, windows-11, gateway

I am running Windows 11 Pro Version 10.0.22624 Build 22624 and currently, after every reboot, my internet connections works for a few minutes, then it is lost. Running the troubleshooter will fix it and the problem every time is "The default gateway is not available":

[image: Screenshot of the result of the internet connection troubleshooter]

Here are some "more information" the troubleshooter provides:

```
Details about network adapter diagnosis: 
Network adapter Ethernet 3 driver information:
 Description . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection
 Manufacturer . . . . . . . . . : Intel Corporation
 Provider . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft
 Version . . . . . . . . . . . : 12.19.1.32
 Inf File Name . . . . . . . . . : C:\WINDOWS\INF\net1ic64.inf
 Inf File Date . . . . . . . . . : Friday, May 6, 2022 2:10:00 PM
 Section Name . . . . . . . . . : E1539.10.0.1.19H1
 Hardware ID . . . . . . . . . . : pci\ven_8086&dev_1539
 Instance Status Flags . . . . . : 0x180200a
 Device Manager Status Code . . : 0
 IfType . . . . . . . . . . . . : 6
 Physical Media Type . . . . . . : 14
```

What could cause this and how to fix it permanently?

The PC is connected through onboard-ethernet of my MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon AC to a FritzBox 6690 Cable.

I already tried disabling power control of the ethernet card, that it cannot be shutdown to save energy to no avail.

According to the comments, I also tried upgrading to version 13 of the driver. While I can upgrade to it:

[[image]

after reboots the driver gets reset to the 12 version.

Comment: I have an I211 as well, driver version is 13.0.14.0 (probably not the latest either) that's something you could look at

Comment: [Try updating your driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/18293/intel-network-adapter-driver-for-windows-10.html) disregard the fact it says “Windows 10 family”.

Comment: @Ramhound I noticed that after updating the driver to 13, after reboot, it uses the 12 one again. That's weird. So the issue persists, but that could also relate to the driver being reset.

Comment: @JaromandaX Look at comment above please.

Comment: Hmm, maybe start with how `ipconfig /all` and `arp -a` look *before and after* the troubleshooter fix (and maybe also before it dies)?

Comment: (1) Have you installed a security product besides Defender? (2) Does it happen on cold boot (no sleep or hibernate)? (3) Perhaps you could try to delete the network driver and let Windows use its generic/built-in drivers.

Comment: @k0pernikus how do you figure that this is a driver problem (it's rather unlikely)? What is your network configuration (router/client IPs, static/dynamic, etc.)? Are there other devices on your network besides the client and the router? Once you loose your internet connection, what happens if you try to ping the router, a different device on your local network (if available) and an internet server (e.g. google)? Is anything different if you compare it to when it's working? Please (also) add this information to your question.